# iOS Hardware UUID

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How are companies like testfairy capturing the hardware id of iOS devices? This is something I've wanted to do but have been continuously been directed towards using the currentDevice.identifierForVendor.

Answer (score 0):

You need an Enterprise Developer license from Apple, then you generate your Enterprise certificates.  Once your enterprise certificate is in place, your tools and libraries should be able to get the actual device UUID rather than a dynamically generated UUID at install.

You can read more on the [Apple Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/) and the associated [Distributing Apple Developer Enterprise Program Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH33-SW1).  During this process, you will probably want to open a Technical Support Incident with Apple to get the gritty details on how to do just that.  But at least you will be on the right path.

Good luck, the work is easy, finding how is challenging.